# I cant get my content in textbox clickable

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, tel

Im newbie and trying edit one file called core.js in my files.

I try add this

```
<div class="txt"><a href="tel://">'+s.desc+"</a></div>
```

But what happens is only the TEL:// become the link and not the content in the desc. the content is showing but the link become only tel://

there will be a number in desc, so i want the link become for example
tel://2332211

What do i missing?

Comment: You're missing code that puts `2332211` into the `<a>` tag?

Comment: If I understand correctly what you're asking, that's not really how it works. The text doesn't just get appended to your href link. You will need to put the number in your href directly or use an actual script (javascript, jquery or whatever) to do this for you

Comment: can you show more of your core.js file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm **assuming** based on your provided string, that this is part of a variable that looks something like:

```
var content = '<div class="txt"><a href="tel://">'+s.desc+"</a></div>";
```

What you're looking for is to re-use `s.desc` *inside* the `a href` as well:

```
var content = '<div class="txt"><a href="tel://'+s.desc+'">'+s.desc+"</a></div>";
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: use ' instead of " in href ;)

Comment: Yeah; got a little confused by the use of both single and double quotes there for a second ;)